# Pyspark - Create Json struct column from Json string column and Schema column

Tags: json, pyspark

I have below data in pyspark dataframe.

[image]

I want to convert the JsonData column which is in string format to JsonStruct format as mentioned in JsonSchema column.

Tried below code -

```
df1 = df.withColumn("NewJson",F.from_json(F.col("JsonData"),df['JsonSchema']))
```

It is not working.

Kindly suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the desired result by doing the following -

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("parsed_data", F.from_json(F.col("NewJson"), F.lit(df1.select("JsonSchema").first()[0])))
```